# Find the conditional distribution of a variable?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Given that a lifetime has the cdf $F(t)=1−(1−t)^n$ for $0≤t≤1$ and some natural $n$.

We wish to find the conditional distribution of the variable $T_x=T−x$, given that $T > x$ and
$0 < x < 1$.

I really need a hint getting started with this question. I am really confused as to what we can imply about $T$. Thanks for any input.

Comment: PS: $n=1$ or you don't have a CDF; unless perhaps you meant $F(t)=1-(1-t)^n$ .

Answer (score 2):

$\begin{eqnarray}F_{T_x|T>x}(a)&=&P(T_x\le a|T>x)\\&=&P(T-x\le a|T>x)\\&=&\frac{P(T-x\le a,T>x)}{P(T>x)}\\&=&\frac{P(x<T\le a+x)}{P(T>x)}\\&=&\frac{F_T(a+x)-F_T(x)}{1-F_t(a)}...(*)\end{eqnarray}$.

Now, the last has been developed for all $a$. Since you know that $F_T(t)=[1-(1-t)n]1_{[0,1]}(t)+1_{(0,\infty)}(t)$, you need to manipulated $(*)$ for some cases of $a$ (for example, if $a+x>1$)